# Pagination in Asp.net core 1.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to include pagination in my product page in asp.net core 1.0. I searched a lot and found:

> @Html.PageListPager

but that's not working in asp.net core 1.0.  How can I do this?

Comment: You mean `Html.PagedListPager`? What's "not working"?

Comment: I installed this package "PagedList.Mvc" but when i used @Html.PagedListPager it gave me an error.

Comment: Why not upgrading to ASP.NET Core 2.0?

Comment: Please don't make me pull answers from you one bit at a time. Consult a [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page and add **all** information relevant to reproducing your error to the question directly.

Comment: @JeroenHeier because i made all project in 1.0 if i upgrades will it gave me an error? i think yes so please confirm me?

Comment: and i think no hosting services still support 2.0 or anyone?